# Embedding YouTube video in Google Slides at specific time

Tags: youtube, google-slides

I'm trying to embed a YouTube video in a Google Slides presentation at a specific time (after about a minute into the video). I select the "Copy video URL at current time":

[image: add video to Presentation menu]

But when I paste that URL into the slide and play the video while presenting, the video always starts from the beginning, not at the specified time. Does anyone know why? I can clearly see in the url the "&t=73" value.

Answer (score 5):

1. Import your video into Google slides
2. right-click on it
3. select "Format options"
4. in the dialogue on the top right, click on "Video playback"
5. set "Start at"

Comment: This works perfectly. Allows you to set start and end dates. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The correct parameter is `&start=73`, not `t`.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I changed the t to start, but it still started playing at the beginning. Here's my link, anything else need to change?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ta_kSaRc80&feature=youtu.be&start =1m9s

Answer (score 1):

The YouTube Insert in Google Sites doesn't allow specifying certain start time for videos.  Here's my work around:

1. Find YouTube Video and Pause it for a "picture"
2. Use "Greenshot" to take a screen shot of a picture of Video
3. Upload and insert picture to Google Sites page
4. Change the "Go To Link" to the YouTube Link that includes the start time parameter.
5. Check "Open This Link In a New Window"

Now when user clicks the image, they are taken to a new window playing the Youtube video at the desired time.

Comment: It works but not really a professional solution. Hope google slides fixes this, otherwise will stop using.

Answer (score -1):

Insert video

Select Video

Go to Format

Go to Formatting options

Go to Video Playback

Change start time